# Select entity containing list, where list argument has specific value

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two tables first one which contains employees:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private double Salary;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
private List<Project> projects;
//getters and setters
}
```

And the second which contains projects:

```
@Entity
public class Project {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
private String name;
@ManyToMany
private List<Employee> employees;
//getters and setters
}
```

I want to select all employees that are currently working at project named for example "ProjectOne". Whats the best way to write this query in hibernate, and is there any option to use TypedQuery? Or i need to use normal Query? I was trying to write something like:

```
Query query= entityManager.createQuery("select e,p from Employee e, Project p where p.name='ProjectOne' ");
List<Employee>queryResultList=query.getResultList();
```

And I'm already getting some response from hibernate, but it is strange reference, which I can't read properly.

EDIT: The answer was easier that I thought it would be. If query returns 2 values, firstly it has to be casted to Object[], and then first value (Employee) can be cast from object[0], and second (Project) from object[1]:

```
Iterator iterator=queryResultList.iterator();
    while(iterator.hasNext()){
        Object[] object= (Object[]) iterator.next();
        Employee emp= (Employee) object[0];
        Project proj= (Project) object[1];
        System.out.println(emp.getFirstName()+" "+emp.getLastName()+" at project "+proj.getName());
    }
```

Comment: you can get a list of employees if you perform a select query on the relation table

Comment: Try this "select e from Employee e join e.Projects p where p.name='ProjectOne'".